# Changing AltGr behaviour

Tags: keyboard, altgr

I mainly use my keyboard for English, but sometimes I write Irish within browser text boxes, which means I need certain vowels accented.

With most I just hold <kbd>AltGr</kbd> and press the vowel and have no problem. It is only when I need á (I notice that <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> doesn't work within this box). Then it autocompletes my gmail address and also presses enter.

I can even <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>AltGr</kbd> the letter for a capitalised letter a. It's just this one letter, and when I'm in the flow of writing I keep hitting it and that is annoying.

I thought it might just be within Chrome where I'm signed in with the email address that gets filled out, but then I tried it within Firefox and there the same thing happens, so I guess it must be set somewhere on Windows 10.

Is there anyone else who uses this letter perhaps in their own language and has had and solved this problem?